# Expression to calculate new column value

Tags: database, ms-access

I am connecting a clients Access database to a website but need to add a new column with data generated from 2 existing columns.

In short:

Column A contains text entries of either "4 Minute", "8 Minute" or "12 Minute".

Column B contains an amount (anything from 0 to 20)

I want to create a new column that runs along the lines of:

```
If Column A = "4 Minute" Then
Column C = Column B * 4
```

And so on.

There are currently around 3000 records to amend before I upload and connect to the website.

Comment: What is the question? And why are you creating a calculated column?

Comment: At present Column A is a session length for customers and Column B is how many they have purchased. This is being replaced with a nes system where customers will purchase an amount of minutes, therefore we need to convert their current sessions and amount of sessions into a minute amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming text values in Column A are always `[0-99] Minute` then this will give you the value of the new column:

```
SELECT Trim(Left(ColumnA, 2))*ColumnB AS ColumnC from MyTable
```

If you want to store this value as a database column (though as @Remou comments ... why would you?) then:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET ColumnC=Trim(left(ColumnA, 2))*ColumnB
```